# Verification failed - function is not called

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to test a function like this:

```
override suspend fun create(item: Location): FlowResult<Location> {
    val (base, version) = locationRepositoryMapper.map(item)
    return locationRemoteSource.create(base, version)
        .flatMapConcat {
            when (it) {
                is Result.Success -> {
                    locationLocalSource.create(
                        base = it.data.first,
                        version = it.data.second
                    )
                }
                else -> flowOf(it)
            }
        }.mapToModel()
}
```

The test itself:

```
@Test
fun `during creating, when data were saved into the remote source and failed to save it locally, then an error should be returned`() =
    runTest {
        // setup
        coEvery { locationRemoteSource.create(any(), any()) } returns flowOf(Result.Success(locationPair))
        coEvery { locationLocalSource.create(any(), any()) } returns flowOf(Result.Failure(mockk()))
        coEvery { locationRepositoryMapper.map(any()) } returns locationPair
        // invoke
        val result = repository.create(mockk())
        // verification
        coVerify(exactly = 1) { locationRemoteSource.create(any(), any()) }
        coVerify(exactly = 1) { locationLocalSource.create(any(), any()) }
        // assertion
        result.collect {
            assertTrue(it.isFailure)
        }
    }
```

The problem that it fails on line:

```
coVerify(exactly = 1) { locationLocalSource.create(any(), any()) }
```

It prints out that **locationLocalSource** is not called

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: LocationLocalSource(#3).create(any(), any(), any())) was not called
```

I don’t know why it happens since according to my understanding if remote source returns success result, then create fun from local source should be called. Where I'm wrong? thank you in advance.

P.S. verification of the remote source passes without problems

update #1: Definition of LocationLocalSource class in a test class

```
private val locationPair = Pair(mockk<LocationBase>(), mockk<LocationVersion>())
private val locationLocalSource = mockk<LocationLocalSource>()
private val locationRemoteSource = mockk<LocationRemoteSource>()
private val locationRepositoryMapper = mockk<RepositoryMapper<Location, LocationBase, LocationVersion>>()
private val repository = LocationRepositoryImpl(
    locationLocalSource = locationLocalSource,
    locationRemoteSource = locationRemoteSource,
    locationRepositoryMapper = locationRepositoryMapper
)
```

Comment: how is `locationLocalSource ` defined in the test? how is the class under test initialized?

Comment: @sidgate, question updated

Comment: seems `LocationLocalSource ` create method has third parameter with some default value. try with `coEvery { locationLocalSource.create(any(), any(), any()) } returns flowOf(Result.Failure(mockk()))`

Comment: @sidgate, create fun has only two params. Anyway, its something with a kotlin flow here. But thank you for a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

1.modify test fun like this:

```
// invoke
val result = runTest {
  repository.create(mockk())
}
```

2.modify runTest fun:

```
fun <T> runTest(block: suspend () -> Flow<T>): List<T> {
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()
    runBlockingTest {
        launch {
            block()
                .onStart {
                    println("${Instant.now()}: starts")
                }
                .onEach {
                    println("${Instant.now()}: $it")
                }
                .onCompletion { ex -> ex?.let {
                    println("${Instant.now()}: $it") }
                }
                .collect {
                    result.add(it)
                }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```